# image positioning within a div using a negative block div - responsive design

Tags: image, responsive-design

I wasn't sure how to explain what I need to do and although I have looked through the forum for answers, I haven't had much luck in finding a specific solution.

I have one image which I'm wanting to place above the blue 100% width panel div element background.  I have tried positioning the image as absolute and float.  The float is more effective but I cannot get it to rise above the blue box when I place a negative margin. It goes under the blue panel.

[image: TEMPLATE]

The blue bg is 100% width and the text should float around the image when the screen is made smaller. The green and orange rectangles are one image.

Here is the html code I have thus far but still experiencing difficulties with either placing the image and having the text to the right wrap around it, or, I can wrap the text but the image does not sit above the blue bg.  This is for a mobile site.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the image - traceyower.co.nz/intended-layout.jpg.

The blue bg is 100% width and the text should float around the image when the screen is made smaller. The green and orange rectangles are one image. –

### HTML:

```html
<div class="gap-box-row">
    <div id="gap-imggroup">
        <img src="..." alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="gap-box1">
        <p class="text1">Collect your FREE ....etc</p>
        <p class="text2"> <a href="..." title="...">Get BOTH</a> or just <a href="..." title="...">Grab a FREE</a><span><img style="float:right; width:32px; height:41px;" src="..." />
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- end gap-box1 -->
</div>
<!-- end box-row -->
```

### CSS:

```css
.gap-box-row {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    clear:both;
}
#gap-imggroup {
    position:absolute;
    width:278px;
    height:280px;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:-75px;
    margin-right:10px;
    left:0;
    top:0%;
    z-index: 10;!important
}
.gap-box1,
.gap-box2,
.gap-box3 {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid #390;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
    -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
    -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;

}
.gap-box1 {
    min-height:278px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color: #0099cc; 
}

.gap-box1 p.text1{
    font: 2em/1.5em normal arial, sans-serif;
    padding:.5em;
    color:#fff;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Do you think you can add a screenshot or a fiddle showing you problem?

Comment: Give us the image link and we can add it.

Comment: Sure.. here's the image - http://www.traceyower.co.nz/intended-layout.jpg.  The blue bg is 100% width and the text should float around the image when the screen is made smaller.  The green and orange rectangles are one image.